# How to validate all rows in a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below is the script in which I am trying to validate if the same name, `id` and `email` exists in a table, the problem is that even if I add a new input for each field I still get a "data already exist", how do I fix this issue, also how to validate using regular expression for each fields. For `id` I need three letters and 3 numbers using regular expression.

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
    $name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : null;
    $ccode = !empty($_POST['id']) ? trim($_POST['id']) : null;
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row['num'] > 0){
        die('The Data already exists!');
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, id, email) VALUES (:name, :id,   :email)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if ($result) {
            echo 'User aadded successfully!';
        }
   } 
}
<form action="sign.php" method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>
<label for="id">id</label>
<input type="text" id="" name="id" required><br>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>
<input type="submit" name="register" value=" Click to Add"></button>
</form>
```

and how do I validate if the fields have same name. For example I have 3 input fields, in the first field I enter the name of a person and in the second or third field if I enter the same name an error should display when I click the submit button, can it be done using a for loop to check each field if it contains the same name.

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you really know `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users` does or it's just some code you copied/inherited?

Comment: why don't you explain it to me

Comment: It counts all rows in the `user` table. So your `$row['num'] > 0` conditional means you can have at most one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uuhm, your check on whether a row already exists with those variables doesn't use any of the variables?

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users"; // Where are the variables?
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();
```

What you'd want to do is:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users WHERE name = :name OR id = :id OR email = :email"; // Where are the variables?
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

$stmt->execute();
```

I'm not too experienced using PDO. prefer MySQLi myself

You should read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Edit:

New query based on comments, just check the doubles in name/manager/senior before hand in PHP:

```
if($name != $manager && $manager != $senior && $name != $senior) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users WHERE (name = :name OR manager = :manager OR senior = :senior)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':manager', $manager);
    $stmt->bindParam(':senior', $senior);

    $stmt->execute();
    // insert other stuff
} else {
    // insert error here
}
```

Full Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
    $name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : null;
    $manager= !empty($_POST['manager']) ? trim($_POST['manager']) : null;
    $senior= !empty($_POST['senior']) ? trim($_POST['senior']) : null;

    if($name != $manager && $manager != $senior && $name != $senior) {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users WHERE (name = :name OR manager = :manager OR senior = :senior)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':manager', $manager);
        $stmt->bindParam(':senior', $senior);

        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row['num'] > 0){
            die('The Data already exists!');
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, manager, senior) VALUES (:name, :manager,   :senior)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':manager', $manager);
            $stmt->bindParam(':senior', $senior);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            if ($result) {
                echo 'User added successfully!';
            }
        }
    } else {
        die('Duplicate in name/manager/senior!');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked!! also how do i validate if two fields have same name

Comment: what do you mean by if two fields have the same name?

Comment: as you can see from the above code i have a name field, and i create two other fields such as manager and senior manager, now i add the same name of a person as in the name field to the manager field and another name for senior manager field, in this case an error should say that the same user names cannot be added..how do i compare the names so that each filed has a different name

Comment: you add those fields to the table users? or to the input form?
and person "bob" can't have a different "bob" as manager?

Comment: yes i have those two fields added to the table users, and i created two text inputs for them below name field, the id and email are replaced with these two fileds, so the table now consists of name, manger and senior manager..now  for instance "bob" is an employee and if i add another person named "bob" having same credentials in either manger or senior manger and error should display..each row stored should have different names because "bob" cannot be a manager or senior manager of himself..so the values can be "bob" "john" "doe" and not "bob" "john" "bob" or "bob" "bob" "bob" or bob,bob,doe.

Comment: Edited, i think this should work. But might contain a mistake, typed it on my phone

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to accept an answer. if you still have question feel free to ask!

Comment: i am getting this error "
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register\user1.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\register\user1.php(29): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register\user1.php on line 29
"

Comment: updated it, better to just check this beforehand in PHP instead of in MySQL anyway. Hope this helps

Comment: :p you should be able to figure that out yourself, but for this one time I have added it into your old code

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark an answer so your question doesn't stay unsolved. Also you should read up more on queries and MySQL and PHP in general.

Comment: just one last query, what to do in a case where  "bob" "john" "doe" and aslo "jane" "john" "doe" here john and doe can be manager and senior for a different person jane, in that case how would the logic change

Comment: you'd change the where statement to just compare the name and not the manager/senior? so what is now `WHERE (name = :name OR manager = :manager OR senior = :senior)` changes to `WHERE name = :name` and of course you wouldn't bind the manager and senior parameter anymore for the check query only for the insert

Answer (score 0):

You Can try:-

```
$name = ($_POST['name']) ? $name = trim($_POST['name']) : $name='';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your following query lines from

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

to this

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM users WHERE name = :name OR id = :id OR email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```